Xcode 16 Storyboard Error - “An internal error occurred.Editting functionality may be limited.”
In Xcode 16, I can't view and develop my designs through storyboard and xib files. Xcode freezes and gives the error “An internal error occurred.Editting functionality may be limited.”
Please, if anyone has solved this problem, can you please share your solution?
I tried reinstalling Xcode from scratch by clearing all the files from caches and the problem is not solved. As far as I understand, there seems to be a problem with UIKit support.

Are you having an issue with a particular storyboard and project or even if you open a new project and create a new storyboard/xib, the issue is happening?

There is nothing we can do about this. Report it to Apple.

Your .storyboard is corrupted, just have a look at your git history if you can

I think re-installing Xcode to isolate a problem is good troubleshooting, but if you open a new project with a storyboard, it will probably work...

i have same issue, in my case when adding new font on my project lead to this error . i still cant solve this error

After 6 hours of trying every solution on the internet: deleting lines in pbxproj, deleting XCode and installing it again, cleaning derived data and cache, creating a new project...
I SOLVED it by updating the cocoapods version (sudo gem update cocoapods)

Is this really an answer to the above question? What does updating CocoaPods have to do with an error about a corrupt storyboard?
